# why is this tetx not overflowing on the x axis even though I have a fixed width and the <p tag is set to display: block?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need the text to overflow on the X axis just to reproduce some issue that I'm having on a bigger project. I leave a simple snippet, so you can tell me where I'm doing it wrong. Thanks!

```css
.article {
  background-color: rgb(236, 161, 161);
  width: 20em;
}

.article p {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
    <article class="article">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Perferendis deleniti iure quidem distinctio officia voluptates similique molestiae culpa? Perferendis, velit maiores nobis maxime aut facere eaque quis voluptas accusamus commodi.</p>

    </article>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the `p` tag to overflow on the x-axis, you simply need to tell it not to wrap using the [white-space](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) property:

```css
article{
    width: 20em;
    background-color: rgb(236, 161, 161);
}

article p{
    display: block;

    /* Do NOT break the text onto a new line when it reaches the container bounds. */
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<article>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Perferendis deleniti iure quidem distinctio officia voluptates similique molestiae culpa? Perferendis, velit maiores nobis maxime aut facere eaque quis voluptas accusamus commodi.
    </p>
</article>
```